# How to change session data and stay on same page?

Tags: symfony

I want to filter the data on my webpage with four tags ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'). Let's say the user is on this page:

```
/data/1/slug-for-one
```

and the user wants the data now filtered for 'c', he clicks on 'c', a var in his session object is changed and the data is filtered correctly while 'reloading' the same page.

How do i construct the link for the filter buttons? Create a special controller, which parses the filter and redirects? Where does the controller gets the url to redirect? I don't want to pass the route/url per GET since the user could do evil things.

Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, it is a bad idea to stroe the filter in the session. What would be then the best way to pass the filter? Is it possible to set some Routing prefix which can be parsed before the actual controller?

example:

```
/filter/c/data/1/slug-for-one
```

Comment: You can use a POST request and add a route for post requests for a special controller that handles this

Comment: Is there a reason why this data must reside in the session data? It just seem like the wrong place. Sounds like it should be a parameter (GET/POST). Also, what if the user has more than one page/tab open with different tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a POST request to send the variable and then handle it with a custom action. Something like this:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DataController.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
// ...

class DataController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/data/{id}/{slug}")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function filterAction($id, $slug)
    {
        $tag = $this->getRequest()->get('tag');

        // ... filter it by tag and 
    }
}
?>
```

Or just make an `if` in the current action which checks if the request is a POST request and then filter it.

```
<?php
if ('POST' == $this->getRequest()->getMethod()) {
    // ... filter
}
?>
```

Comment: This would work for one route/page. The filter needs to be active on all pages and there has to be minimum one tag selected. This would result in every link sending POST data which sounds ugly.